# Select node with class name and inner text using Xpath

Tags: html, xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I got the following (simplified) HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <li class="item c-MessageRow green">
            <div>Hello and </div>
            <div>welcome
                <div> to</div>
            </div>
            <div> my site</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Now I'd like to select the li element which has the class "c-MessageRow" and contains the inner text "welcome to my site".

I've tried the following:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'c-MessageRow') and contains(text(), 'welcome to my site')]
```

But it returns nothing. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you e.g. change the Xpath to

```
//li[contains(@class, 'c-MessageRow') and contains(div/text(), 'Hello')]
```

or

```
//li[contains(@class, 'c-MessageRow') and 
     contains(div/following-sibling::div/text(), 'welcome')]
```

the `li` is returned.
The issue with your Xpath is that the `li` with the class c-MessageRow does not contain the text 'welcome to my site', but a `div` with the text 'Hello', another `div` with the text 'welcome' etc. Question is if you have to check if the full text is contained in the `li` or if matching only a part of it is sufficient.

**Update** for the comment: Checking for the class and the complete text of the li could be done like this:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'c-MessageRow') and 
  contains(normalize-space(string(self::li)), 'welcome to my site')]
```

The `normalize-space()` takes care about removing any trailing or leading whitespace and linebreaks. This is necessary as using the Xpath `string(//li)` (results may vary, tested with an online Xpath tester) looks like this:

```
Hello and 
        welcome
             to

         my site
```

while using `normalize-space(string(//li))` results in:

```
Hello and welcome to my site
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I thought text() returned the entire inner text of the node (with the inner texts of all subnodes) but am I right to assume it only returns the direct inner text of the first node?

Comment: @JensOlsen112 Yes, you got that right. And the `li` itself doesn't contain any text. You'll get the full text of the `li` using `string` - e.g. `string(//li)` (just as aside, as this might not be useful for your match pattern).

Comment: Ahh I didn't know about the string() method. Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for!